# Как показать кнопу

Tags: android

Есть меню, кнопка btn1 скрыта. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии в меню на "показать кнопку" она появлялась.
Следующий код работать не хочет:

```
case 1:
btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
break;
```

Comment: На интерес спрошу: а за что это так вас заминусили?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено.

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```